# Issue with UIAlertView buttons

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

In my app, I've allocated a new `UIAlertView`...A keyboard pops up in conjunction with its appearance and I can enter whatever I like into the `UIAlertView's` textfield.

I'm having a problem where, when I type on the keyboard, the color of the button located at index one on the `UIAlertView` changes every time I strike a key.

I've tried looking at all the right, obvious places...But cannot solve this.

I know a callback is triggered when I hit a key...But yeah.

Please help.

thanks

Comment: It appears that you've added a text field to your UIAlertView.  If you look at [Apple's UIAlertView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html), it specifically states (under "Subclassing Notes"): "`The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified`".  Create your own subclassed UIView which you control the hierarchy and behavior of and modify *that* instead.

Comment: Thankyou, this method was causing the conflict. - (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView;

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I suggest you add your idea as answer.